# Spacemacs: install a package from the emacs wiki?

Tags: spacemacs, dot-emacs

tl;dr: Install a package in spacemacs from the EmacsWiki (https://www.emacswiki.org) using quelpa with the "wiki fetcher".

As I understand, spacemacs uses `use-package` under the hood.

I would like to automate the installation of `bookmark+` (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/bookmark+.el) package, which is only available (in a most up-to-date form) on the emacs wiki .

The installation is with use package:

```lisp
(use-package bookmark+
                 :quelpa (bookmark+ :fetcher wiki
                                    :files
                                    ("bookmark+.el"
                                     "bookmark+-mac.el"
                                     "bookmark+-bmu.el"
                                     "bookmark+-1.el"
                                     "bookmark+-key.el"
                                     "bookmark+-lit.el"
                                     "bookmark+-doc.el"
                                     "bookmark+-chg.el"))
                 :defer 2)
```

How do I translate this `use-package` in a spacemacs way, e.g. to use in `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` or in my private layer?

I suspect quelpa builds are only supported with the `local` fetcher, which would mean I have to download the package from the wiki manually, which is what I don't want to do.